# How do I run a filter on pg_dump data during an import?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

Using a terminal on Mac OSX (iTerm2) with no external apps except for postgres, I want to run some regex find/replaces on a rather large (52 MB) pg_dump data file as it's being imported into a PostgreSQL database. I need to do this before the dump file hits PostgreSQL because I have to transform the incoming SQL queries that create and modify tables.

The shell command I'm using to import the data is:

```
psql MyDatabase < mydata.sql
```

Is there a way to pipe the data through a regex find/replace filter? Can I do something with native Linux command line utilities like grep?

Alternatively, how would I batch my regex's and apply them to my dump file and then save the changes to a new file?

Comment: The question at the moment is totally useless. Say `regex find/replace` what?  Having spend time here, you don't know what makes a  [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @sjsam I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Please edit the question adding info about the `pattern` you wish to replace and the `new pattern`. Also consider adding the tools you've at your disposal like `sed` `awk` and so.

Comment: @sjsam I believe I hit the main points, which is to transform data from a pg_dump file on import using regex. I even listed what tools I'm using - iTerm2 is a bash shell.

Comment: Mentioning the `shell` alone is of no avail.  What tools in shell you've got is the major concern here.

Comment: @sjsam Assume there are none, and suggest one if you have a solution. There's no reason for a down vote on this.

Comment: Forget my downvote -which i am ready to retract -  somebody has already casted a close vote on this

Comment: If I suggest a general solution `sed s/pattern/newpattern/g file` how may I verify that it is going to help you?

Comment: @sjsam, this should have been an easy answer for you. I wasn't asking for advice on pattern matching. As my question states, I needed to know how to take my data file and pipe it through something that will allow me to transform it with regular expressions as it is imported into postgres. My advice to you is to loosen up a little bit and try to be less punitive. Not everyone is a shell scripting guru like you are.

Comment: In fact I wasn't trying to be very punitive but I could understand the main intention - **ie piping**- only from  the answer  below. Retracting my downvote too.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` that understands regular expressions.

For example, to replace all occurrences of "myschema" that are surrounded by word boundaries with "anotherschema", you could use:

```
sed -e 's/\bmy\(schema\)\b/another\1/g' mydata.sql | psql MyDatabase
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. What if I have multiple regex to run? Is there a way to execute them all at once?

Comment: Sure. Just supply multiple `-e` options.

Comment: Thanks for the sed advice. Apparently if you're not up on your Linux commands you're questions aren't tolerated. If you feel like my question wasn't stupid, maybe you can upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively, how would I batch my regex's and apply them to my dump
> file and then save the changes to a new file?

```
sed -e 's/\bmy\(schema\)\b/another\1/g' mydata.sql >mysqlnew.sql
```

This redirects the output to a new file named `mysqlnew.sql`.

Note that `sed` supports inplace edit option. Using the inplace edit `-i` option, the command above can be replaced by

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\bmy\(schema\)\b/another\1/g' mydata.sql
```

This command makes a copy of the original `mydata.sql` to `mydata.sql.bak` and
makes the changes permanently written to `mydata.sql`.

Comment: there should be a dash before the `-i` option

Comment: @RobertMikes oh yeah! There should be one. Thank you